# How to instert data from jetpack compose to mongo database?

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to figure out how I can create 2 different textfields (name and phone-number) in jetpack compose that when the user enters this type of info and press the continue button, the information will asynchronously save until the person is navigated/enters the "mainscreen". After the user enters the "mainscreen" in this case just a screen with a column saying hello, will the information be saved in mongoDatabase. How can I achieve this? Appreciate the help and feedback!

This is the code so far:

The screen with name, phonenumber and a continue button:

https://gyazo.com/12f15eac19a25f19c3ac1fea42820ab0

```
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .weight(1f),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {

                OutlinedTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(0.80f),
                    value = name,
                    onValueChange = onNameChanged,
                    colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                        focusedBorderColor = LightBlue,
                    ),
                    label = {
                        Text(
                            text = "Name", // Goes top in a small text
                            color = LightBlue,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                        )
                    },
                    placeholder = {
                        Text(
                            text = "Enter your name", // Gives a hint to the user
                            color = Color.Black
                        )
                    },
                    singleLine = true,
                    leadingIcon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Person,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    },
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

                OutlinedTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.8f),
                    value = phoneNumber,
                    onValueChange = { phoneNumber = it },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                    ),
                    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                        onDone = {
                            // You can perform an action here when the user presses Done on the keyboard.
                            // For example, hide the keyboard.
                            keyboardController?.hide()
                        }
                    ),
                    singleLine = true,
                    textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.copy(fontSize = 16.sp),
                    colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                        focusedBorderColor = Color.Blue,
                        unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Gray
                    ),
                    label = {
                        Text(
                            text = "Phone Number", // Goes top in a small text
                            color = LightBlue,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                        )
                    },
                    placeholder = { Text(text = "Enter your telephone number") },

                    leadingIcon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Phone,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    },
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentSize()
                    .fillMaxWidth(0.8f)
                    .height(80.dp)
                    .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp, bottom = 40.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally), // Align the button at the bottom center
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(ConfirmButtonColor),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                onClick = {
                    if (name.isNotEmpty() && phoneNumber.isNotEmpty()) {
                        navController.navigate(AuthScreen.GenderProfile.route)

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Not all fields are filled-in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                },
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Confirm",
                    color = Color.White,
                )
            }
```

Person Class:

```
class Person : RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.invoke()
    var owner_id: String = ""

    // Profile
    var name: String = ""
    var phoneNumber: Int = 0

}
```

MongoRepository:

```
interface MongoRepository {
    fun configureTheRealm()
    fun getData(): Flow<List<Person>>
    suspend fun insertPerson(person: Person)
    suspend fun updatePerson(person: Person)
}
```

MongoDB Object:

```
object MongoDB : MongoRepository {
    private val app = App.create(APP_ID)
    private val user = app.currentUser
    private lateinit var realm: Realm

    init {
        configureTheRealm()
    }

    override fun configureTheRealm() {
        if (user != null) {
            val config = SyncConfiguration.Builder(
                user,
                setOf(Person::class)
            )
                .initialSubscriptions { sub ->
                    add(query = sub.query<Person>(query = "owner_id == $0", user.id))
                }
                .log(LogLevel.ALL)
                .build()
            realm = Realm.open(config)
        }
    }

    override fun getData(): Flow<List<Person>> {
        return realm.query<Person>().asFlow().map { it.list }
    }

    override suspend fun insertPerson(person: Person) {
        if (user != null) {
            realm.write {
                try {
                    copyToRealm(person.apply { owner_id = user.id })
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.d("MongoRepository", e.message.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override suspend fun updatePerson(person: Person) {
        realm.write {
            val queriedPerson =
                query<Person>(query = "_id == $0", person._id)
                    .first()
                    .find()
            if (queriedPerson != null) {
                queriedPerson.name = person.name
                queriedPerson.phoneNumber = person.phoneNumber
            } else {
                Log.d("MongoRepository", "Queried Person does not exist.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HomeViewModel:

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var objectId = mutableStateOf("")
    var data = mutableStateOf(emptyList<Person>())

    // Profile + PickGender screen
    var name = mutableStateOf("")
    var phoneNumber = mutableStateOf(0)
    
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            MongoDB.getData().collect {
                data.value = it
            }
        }
    }

    fun updateObjectId(id: String) {
        this.objectId.value = id
    }

    fun updateName(name: String) {
        this.name.value = name
    }

    fun updatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber: Int) {
        this.phoneNumber.value = phoneNumber
    }
    


    // The phoneNumber and Age will be set in string since I don't know how to set it in Int form
    fun insertPerson() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            if (
                name.value.isNotEmpty() &&
                phoneNumber.value.toString().isNotEmpty() &&
            ) {
                MongoDB.insertPerson(person = Person().apply {
                    name = this@HomeViewModel.name.value
                    phoneNumber = this@HomeViewModel.phoneNumber.value

                })
            }
        }
    }

    fun updatePerson() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            if (objectId.value.isNotEmpty()) {
                MongoDB.updatePerson(person = Person().apply {
                    _id = ObjectId(hexString = this@HomeViewModel.objectId.value)
                    name = this@HomeViewModel.name.value
                    phoneNumber = this@HomeViewModel.phoneNumber.value

                })
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing and editing `ViewModel` variables from your views is a very bad practice. Here's another way to temporarily save values till the user goes to the next screen: Use the [`remember` API](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#retrigger-remember) to save the states of the `TextField`s between recompositions. At the `Button`'s click, you then call the save function you have at the `ViewModel`.

```
var name by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
var phoneNumber by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }


OutlinedTextField(
   value = name,
   onValueChange = { name = it },
   ...
)
```

Comment: Yes that is true, will update it with either remember API or savedstatehandle but my biggest concern at the moment is: How can I save the information to mongo database when the user enters their information? Am I missing something in the code for it to insert the infromation to monogdatabse or do I need to initialize it some way? @Eliza Camber

Comment: The `inserPerson` fun doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, it seems to me that I need to initialize mongoDb with either using sign-in with google or e-mail/pass before I can perform CRUD operations. Is there no way around this? @Eliza Camber

Comment: I'm not that familiar with mongoDB but you can try either A. assigning random user IDs to your users before attempting insertion (I'd think that this is what mongo or any DB would care for), or B. I created a guide on Google's OneTap & firebase sign in here if you would like to have a look: https://tutorials.amity.co/login-flow-with-google-identity-services-and-firebase-98b454fed021

Comment: @JosefM is there a reason you need to add to the mongoDB directly upon update to the textfields?

Comment: Will take a look and see but yes, Mongodb assigns random user Id:s to every person that is inserted but I am still not sure how to add that person into mongoDb since whenever I use google or facebook auth, mongoDb creates a schema but is there a way to create this schema without the use of google, facebook or any other auth platform? @ElizaCamber

Comment: No I dont mind it being added after, but is there a way to create the schema using non-auth methods ? @Haroon

Comment: Just assigning random UUIDs should work the same as Google or FB auth

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB is a NoSQL database, and it does not require integration with Google Sign-In or email/password authentication for basic CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations.

If you are using MongoDB Realm, a serverless platform by MongoDB, you might be referring to the authentication methods it provides. Realm supports various authentication providers, including anonymous authentication, email/password, and OAuth 2.0 providers such as Google.

You can enable anonymous authentication in MongoDB Realm if you don't want to prompt users to provide credentials. This way, users can perform CRUD operations without signing in.

Here's an example of how you might use anonymous authentication with MongoDB Realm:

1. Enable Anonymous Authentication in the MongoDB Realm Dashboard:
   Navigate to the Realm UI, find the "Authentication" section, and
   enable "Allow users to log in anonymously."
2. Authenticate Anonymously in Your Android App: You can use the Realm SDK to log in anonymously:

````
    app.loginAsync(Credentials.anonymous()) {
        if (it.isSuccess) {
            Log.v("AUTH", "Successfully authenticated anonymously.")
            // You can now insert a person into the database
            insertPerson()
        } else {
            Log.e("AUTH", "Failed to authenticate anonymously.", it.error)
        }
    }```
````

Comment: And by using anonymous authentication, mongoDb will create the schema necessary to being able to add information into monog database ? @Haroon

Comment: can you confirm if you're using mongoDB or mongoDB Realm? mongoDB Realm is a Firebase alternative

Comment: at the moment MongoDB only!

Comment: I will most likely transfer over to MongoDb Realm within the near future since its better adapted to mobile development!